# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_chk' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I have created a Bank Management System using Tkinter and MySQL in Python.

```
def deposit_acc_chk():
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM bank_master WHERE acno = '"+deposit_entry1.get()+"'")
for x in mycursor:
    name_chk = ''.join(map(str, x))
deposit_chk_entry.delete(0, "end")
deposit_chk_entry.insert(0, name_chk)
deposit_chk_entry["state"] = "disabled"
```

This code snippet displays the name of the Account holder depositing the money. It was working fine initially but then it showed an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\BMS - GUI v1.1.2.py", line 196, in deposit_acc_chk
    deposit_chk_entry.insert(0, name_chk)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_chk' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to declare the variable `name_chk`, explicitly, as global and even tried referring some already answered questions of this type but it was not much helpful.
My error is still not resolved! Please help me.

P.S. - I am new here so please excuse me if I fail to correctly describe my question!

Comment: It is because the SQL statement does not return any record, so `name_chk` is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is no record returned by the SQL statement, so `name_chk` is not created.

You should check whether there is record returned before updating `deposit_chk_entry`:

```
def deposit_acc_chk():
    mycursor.execute('SELECT name FROM bank_master WHERE acno = %s', (deposit_entry1.get(),))
    rec = mycursor.fetchone()
    if rec:
        deposit_chk_entry['state'] = 'normal'
        deposit_chk_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        deposit_chk_entry.insert(0, rec[0])
        deposit_chk_entry['state'] = 'disabled'
```

Or better show something to user if no record found:

```
def deposit_acc_chk():
    mycursor.execute('SELECT name FROM bank_master WHERE acno = %s', (deposit_entry1.get(),))
    rec = mycursor.fetchone()
    name_chk = rec[0] if rec else '*** No record found ***'
    deposit_chk_entry['state'] = 'normal'
    deposit_chk_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    deposit_chk_entry.insert(0, name_chk)
    deposit_chk_entry['state'] = 'disabled'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should

- **declare** the `name_chk` variable before the line (*this way, initialization occurs too*)

  `deposit_chk_entry.insert(0, name_chk)` such as

  ```
  import tkinter as tk

  root = tk.Tk()
  name_chk = tk.StringVar()
  ```

or

- **call** `deposit_acc_chk()` function between end of this function and
  the line `deposit_chk_entry.insert(0, name_chk)` in order to incur the definition of the variable
  `name_chk` within that function